# Display a Tablix on click of Image in ssrs.

Tags: reporting-services

We have one requirement in SSRS where we need to display the tablix on click of the Image. By default tablix will be hidden, when user clicks on the Image then we need to show the hidden tablix. Kindly suggest some solution if any. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the visibility of an object. Initially have the visibility property set to hidden, then use the toggleitem property to accomplish what you are looking for. Instructions are below

To hide static rows in a table, matrix, or list:

1. In report design view, click the table, matrix, or list to display
   the row and column handles.
2. Right-click the row handle, and then click Row Visibility. The Row Visibility dialog box opens.
3. To set the visibility, follow steps 3 and 4 in the first procedure.
4. To hide static columns in a table, matrix, or list
5. In Design view, select the table, matrix, or list to display the row and column handles.
6. Right-click the column handle, and then click Column Visibility.
7. In the Column Visibility dialog box, follow steps 3 and 4 in the first procedure.
8. Then use the ToggleItem property of the table.  Select the table, locate the property in the Properties window and specify the name of the textbox.  If you now render the report you'll notice a little + icon in front of the testingBox content.
9. To find out what your textbox is called first select that and look at the bold part in top of the Properties window.  To change it you can use the Name property.  It's advisable to give it a clear name so you can easily locate it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Generally, answers should have more explanatory content than just links. A good rule of thumb is, "Would the answer still be useful without the links?" You should try to add some more content to your answer so that your answer can be understood without following the links.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware. I'll fix this.